# Push DIV below first fold? Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, viewport

Is there a way to "push" a div below the first fold so that it never shows up on page load unless the user scrolls down?  I know there is something called Jquery viewport but not sure how to use it.  I don't want the DIV to be "hidden" with CSS either.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need any javascript! Just good 'ole CSS. Set the element that is a child of the `<body>` to `position:absolute; top:100%;` and you've got your below-the-fold-element.

```
.below {
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
}
```

Plus, unlike setting a static top or margin with javascript, this will work even after you resize your browser window.

Here's a jsFiddle with the full markup: http://jsfiddle.net/ubhBL/

Comment: +1, for some reason I thought that `top : 100%` on a `position : absolute` element would push it to the bottom of the document, not just the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: @shruggernaut You are mistaken. The OP does not use a word even similar to "insert." The question clearly asks about positioning an element relative to the visual viewport -- not reposition within the DOM. In fact, one could not even make the assumption that the DOM extends beyond the page-fold to insert correctly. The solution I provided (nearly four years ago, mind you) solves the problem as it was asked: "Is there a way to "push" a div below the first fold so that it never shows up on page load unless the user scrolls down?" and does so without knowing the content length or viewport size.

Comment: is there a way to do that while keeping the element in the "flow" of the document?

Answer (score 2):

How about using jQuery to set a `top` or `margin-top` CSS property for your element that is equal to the height of the `viewport`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#my-under-the-fold-element').css({
        top : $(window).height()
    });
});
```

Then you just need to make your element absolutely positioned.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CtgUB/2/